# What is the difference between store.destroy() and session.destroy()? Do we need to use both?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to implement/destroy sessions in my web app now, but I'm confused because there seems to be two ways to destroy sessions. Should I use both, store.destroy and session.destroy, or only one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`store.destroy()` can be used to destroy a specific session from server. where `session.destroy()` will destroy the current session
https://github.com/expressjs/session